# Autozoom when following plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with two (or more) subplots.

I frequently pan or move the axes when looking at the plot.

With the following snippet, I am already able that one subplot follows the other with regard to the x axis - that means, that moving/zooming the x-axis for one subplot will accordingly move/zoom the other x-axis, too.

How can I achieve, that when zooming/moving the x-axis, also the other subplot gets autozoomed for its y-axis?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
xValues = np.linspace(0, 10, 10 + 1)
yValues1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10 + 1)
yValues2 = np.linspace(0, -10, 10 + 1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(yValues1, index=xValues)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(yValues2, index=xValues)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))

ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
axes = [ax1, ax2]
dfs = [df1, df2]

for ax, dfRunner in zip(axes, dfs):
    ax.plot(dfRunner, "-o", markersize=2)
    plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=20)
    ax.grid()
    plt.gca().fmt_xdata = lambda x: mdates.num2date(x).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand correctly, but I think what you want is to replace your `plt.figure()` and `plt.subplot()` commands with `fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)`.

Comment: Thanks for your question. No, my question refers to the point how after using move or zoom the other plot autozooms for the y axis.