# Autoscaling y should only extend to what x allows to show

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with two (or more) subplots.

I frequently pan or move the axes when looking at the plot.

With the following snippet, I am already able that one subplot follows the other with regard to the x axis - that means, that moving/zooming the x-axis for one subplot will accordingly move/zoom the other x-axis, too.

Additionally I am able to achieve that leaving the axis puts the y_min and y_max for one subplot back to the values the **overall**  y data have.

But what I would like to have is that the view for that screen only extends to what can be visible according to the visible values of x.

How do I have to change my code that y is scaled to what x only allows to show?

Remark: this question is a follow-up for [Autozoom when following plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356898/autozoom-when-following-plot-in-matplotlib)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def enter_axes(event):
    print('enter_axes', event.inaxes)
    event.inaxes.patch.set_facecolor('yellow')
    event.canvas.draw()
def leave_axes(event):
    print('leave_axes', event.inaxes)
    event.inaxes.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    event.canvas.figure.axes[0].autoscale(enable=True, axis='y')
    # event.canvas.figure.axes[0].autoscale(enable=True, axis='x')
    # event.inaxes.patch.set_autoscaley_on()
    event.canvas.draw()
def enter_figure(event):
    print('enter_figure', event.canvas.figure)
    event.canvas.figure.patch.set_facecolor('red')
    event.canvas.draw()
def leave_figure(event):
    print('leave_figure', event.canvas.figure)
    event.canvas.figure.patch.set_facecolor('grey')
    event.canvas.draw()
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1.suptitle('mouse hover over figure or axes to trigger events')
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
ax1.set_autoscale_on(True)

ax1.plot([1,1.8, 2,2.2, 3], [3,3.8, 4,4.2, 5],"-o")
ax2.plot([1,1.8, 2,2.2, 3], [3,3.8, 4,4.2, 5],"-o")
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_enter_event', enter_figure)
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_leave_event', leave_figure)
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', enter_axes)
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_leave_event', leave_axes)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

I update the code a little, to explain my requirement a little bit better and added the screenshot below. For the screenshot, I zoomed in the lower subplot and therefore the x-constraints of (x_min = 1.8, x_max = 2.2) are also set for the upper subplot.

I would like to have in the upper subplot also y-constraints of (y_min = 3.75, y_max = 4.3). Presently the visible y-constraints are (y_min = 3.00, y_max = 5.00), as this is the hole range of y.

[image: screenshot after zooming in lower subplot]

Comment: What is *"what x allows to show"*?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I hope that I have explained it with my edited post a little bit better.

Comment: There is no build-in feature for this. You will need to get the x limits, use them to calculate the new y limits and set those new ylimits.